# What is transform and what is Transform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform[] waypoint;
    public float patrolSpeed;
    public bool loop = true;
    public int dampingLook = 4;
    public float pauseDuration;
    private float curTime;
    private int currentWaypoint = 0;
    public CharacterController character;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


    }

    void LateUpdate(){

        if(currentWaypoint < waypoint.Length){
            patrol();
        }else{    
            if(loop){
                currentWaypoint= 0;
            } 
        }
    }

    void patrol(){

        Vector3 nextWayPoint = waypoint[currentWaypoint].position;

        // Keep waypoint at character's height
        nextWayPoint.y = transform.position.y; 

        // Get the direction we need to move to
        // reach the next waypoint
        Vector3 moveDirection = nextWayPoint - transform.position;
```

Is transform meaning the character ? So transform.position will get the character position in this case ThirdPersonController i added the script to it ? How the script know to belong the transform to the character ?

And if i'm doing Transform _transform then what is the difference between the _transform and the transform i'm using now ?

If i want to set or get the character start position for example i could make in the script: public Transform _transform; then in the start function: _transform = GetComponent(); then for example i could get the position from the _transform ?

Comment: Don't tag your question with irrelevant tags.

Comment: really, SO is not a "tutorial" oriented site.

Comment: never, ever, ever use variable names including underscore, for any reason.

Comment: @Joe Disagree, this is personal preference. It is also supported in all Lexical Analysers I know of. There might be best practices where they say you shouldn't use the underscore. But beware, there are also best practices where you use the underscore.

Comment: hi Nöel, Just TBC I was specifically addressing the OP, TheLostLostit.  TheLostLostit, you should never use variable names including underscore, for any reason.  It's completely irrelevant in Unity, particularly if you are apparently just a beginner and do not even know what a Transform v. transform is.  So, enjoy - but no underscores!  :)

Comment: This question isn't relevant since all this is explained on the documentation -> Transform(type): https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html and transform(component): https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, **Transform is a Type** where as **transform is a property** of type Transform.
If you retrieve transform you will always get the Transform of the GameObject your script is assigned to.

In your example transform refers to the Transform of the Waypoint.
If you want to recieve the Transform of the character you'll have to retrieve it using character.transform.

You have probably seen people doning:

```
private Transform _transform;
```

We do this to cache the Transform of the current GameObject into our own member because calling transform can be a small performance hit if you do it very often. However, we still need to call transform at least once to actually retrieve the reference:

```
private void Awake(){
   _transform = transform;
}
```

EDIT:
To set your characters position you can use:

```
character.transform.position = someVector3;
```

Comment: Hi Noël - good news, they vastly improved `GameObject` and `Component` in U5 so there is no need to cache .transform that way these days.

Comment: So i can store the start position of my character by doing in the Start function: someVector3 = character.transform.position; right ? And then i wonder how do i add this someVector3 to the waypoint array at index 0 but not to replace index 0 but to push the already two indexs in the array. So someVector3 will be in index 0 and the two other index will be pushed to index 1 and 2. ?

Comment: @TheLostLostit Indeed, that is how you retrieve the position. The dynamic areay is another problem. Whenever you are dealing with a dynamic ammount of items you want to store you should be using lists instead of arrays. private List<Vector3> _positions; Then you can add positions like that: _positions.Add(someVector3); Note that this adds someVector3 to the end of the list. Use InsertAt to add a vector somewhere else.

Comment: @JoeBlow Really, too bad we cannot view the source without having to purchase that option. Do they store the reference themselfs now?

Comment: @TheLostLostit Also, your waypoint array is of type Transform. If you were to use arrays you still would have to change the type to Vector3.